# How to sum the integer inside array of arrays?

Tags: arrays, ruby

```
a = [[5, 6], [6, 5], [7, 4], [1, 0, 0], [9, 9], [6, 8], [8, 6], [1, 8, 0], [9, 0]]
```

How can I sum the integers inside the inner array and return an array of sum of the inner array?

I need it to return `[(5+6), (6+5), (7+4), (1+0+0), ...]`, thus `[11, 11, 11, 1, 18, 14, 14, 9, 9]`

Comment: When asking, we expect to see evidence of your effort toward solving the problem. It looks like you're asking us to write the code for you, which is not what we do. Please read "[ask]", including the linked pages, and "[mcve]".

Comment: @theTinMan definitely! I did all my scratch work on https://repl.it/ for almost a good hour, but later I closed the page so I could not show the codes I have tried. I will do so next time. Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
a.map{|a| a.inject(:+)}
# => [11, 11, 11, 1, 18, 14, 14, 9, 9]
```

Comment: You're a ninja. Beat me by 18 seconds because my response was too short

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
sum_arry = a.map { |sub_arry| sub_arry.inject(&:+) }
```

Then `sum_arry` should be the array you want.

Answer (score 4):

Use `map` + `reduce`

```
a.map { |a| a.reduce(:+) }
```

Comment: If all one can usefully say as an answer to a question is 29 characters or less, is the question really worth answering?

Comment: I personally thought it was a pretty good question. Answers are good if they can be less than 30 chars. Just my opinion

Comment: Any other interesting ways to do this?